# Last Day of Month - DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Good evening, I have the following data in Pandas DataFrame:

| Date | DT_INI |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 01032021 |
| 2021-02-06 | 06022021 |

I wish to convert any of these 2 columns to get the last day of its data month.

[image]

Already tried lots of function.. but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`pd.offset.MonthEnd(n=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=monthend#anchored-offset-semantics) as offset to add on the base dates to get the month-end dates, as follows:

```
df['Date_Month_End'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)


print(df)

        Date   DT_INI Date_Month_End
0 2021-03-01  1032021     2021-03-31
1 2021-02-06  6022021     2021-02-28
```

Parameter `n=0` is specified so that Date of `2021-03-31` will not roll forward to `2021-04-30`